# Why won't my C# stack output the contents even after I use peek and push?

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine, stack, peek

I am trying to get my stack called rpnstack to output its contents from an xml file that looks like this:

```
<mrow>
<apply>
  <eq/>
  <apply>
    <plus/>
    <apply>
      <power/>
      <ci>5</ci>
      <cn>2</cn>
    </apply>
    <apply>
      <times/>
      <cn>4</cn>
      <ci>2</ci>
    </apply>
    <cn>4</cn>
  </apply>
  <cn>0</cn>
</apply>
</mrow>
```

> My rpn stack below will not output anything, am I not running into the ifs? I am attempting to parse out the mathml tags and I am trying to store all of the values of the equation like: 5^2 + 4*2 + 4 = 0

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Xml;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;

    namespace ParseXML
    {
        class PARSEMATH : MonoBehaviour
        {
            Stack<string> stacknums = new Stack<string>();
            Stack<string> stacktags = new Stack<string>();
            Stack<string> stacknumandtags = new Stack<string>();

            Stack<string> rpnstack = new Stack<string>();

            void Start()
            {
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                TextAsset textAsset = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("testing");
                xmlDoc.LoadXml(textAsset.text);

                foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
                {
                    string text = node.InnerText;
                    stacknums.Push(text);

                    char[] values = text.ToCharArray();

                    string tags = node.OuterXml;
                    stacktags.Push(tags);

                    string numtag = node.OuterXml;
                    stacknumandtags.Push(numtag);

                    Debug.Log(text);
                    Debug.Log(tags);
                    Debug.Log(numtag);

                    int count = 0;

                    foreach(var obj in stacknumandtags)
                    {
                        if(obj == "<eq/>")
                        {
                            // pass over and place = in RPN stack
                            rpnstack.Push("=");
                        }
                        else if (obj == "<plus/>")
                        {
                            // pass over and place = in RPN stack
                            rpnstack.Push("+");

                        }
                       else if (obj == "<power/>")
                        {
                            // pass over and place = in RPN stack
                            rpnstack.Push("^");

                        }
                        else if (obj == "<ci>" || obj == "<cn>")
                        {
                            char num = values[count];

                            string num_ = num.ToString();

                                // pass over and place = in RPN stack
                             rpnstack.Push(num_);

                                // counter
                             count++;


                        }
                        else if(obj == "<times/")
                        {
                            rpnstack.Push("*");

                        }

                        Debug.Log(rpnstack.Peek());
                        Debug.Log(rpnstack.Pop());


                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should use the Debugger to set a breakpoint to check why it doesn't enter the `if`s. And if you're not able, use `Debug.Log(obj)` to show its content in the foreach-loop.

Comment: You only push one thing into `stacknumandtags` which is the `OuterXml` of the first apply node so that's not going to be equal to any of the values you compare to.  I highly recommend that you switch to the new `Linq.Xml` Dom and use `XDocument` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are not navigating down into the elements.  Here's a method that will parse the mathml with recursion instead of stacks.  The stack method doesn't work well when an operator can be applied to multiple operands which is the case with the plus that applies to the 5^2 and the 4*2 and the final 4.

```
public string ReadMathXml(XElement element)
{
    switch(element.Name.LocalName)
    {
        // There should be one apply inside of a row
        case "mrow":
            return ReadMathXml(element.Element("apply"));
        // The apply should have one operator followed by multiple operands
        case "apply":
            var elements = element.Elements();
            var op = ReadMathXml(elements.First());
            var operands = elements.Skip(1).Select(x => ReadMathXml(x));
            return string.Join(op, operands);
        // Add more operators as needed.
        case "plus": return "+";
        case "power": return "^";
        case "eq": return "=";
        case "times" : return "*";
        // Add any other operand names here.
        case "ci" :
        case "cn" : return element.Value;
    }

    // we should not get here.
    return null;
}
```

Then if you call it with this code

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<mrow>
<apply>
  <eq/>
  <apply>
    <plus/>
    <apply>
      <power/>
      <ci>5</ci>
      <cn>2</cn>
    </apply>
    <apply>
      <times/>
      <cn>4</cn>
      <ci>2</ci>
    </apply>
    <cn>4</cn>
  </apply>
  <cn>0</cn>
</apply>
</mrow>");

var result = ReadMathXml(doc.Root);
```

The result will be

> 5^2+4*2+4=0

Note you'll need a `using System.Xml.Linq;` to be able to use `XDocument` and `XElement`.